# How can I load all child records recursively?

Tags: c#, recursion, entity-framework-core, yield-return

I have this Project class:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<Project> ChildProjects { get; set; }
    // more properties
}
```

This is my attempt to load all descendants of any given project:

```
private async Task<List<Project>> LoadDescendantsOf(Project project)
{
    project.ChildProjects = await db.Projects
        .Where(p => p.ParentId == project.Id)
        .ToListAsync();
    foreach (Project childProject in project.ChildProjects)
    {
        yield return childProject.ChildProjects = 
            await LoadDescendantsOf(childProject);
    }
}
```

... but it's not working. The error message I get is

> The body of 'ProjectsController.LoadDescendantsOf(Project)' cannot be an iterator block because 'Task>' is not an iterator interface type

I have tried making the method synchronous, but it's the same error message, only without the "Task"-part.

How can I make it work?

Comment: I don't know if you can use yield in combination with tasks, but yield will only work when the return type is `IEnumerable<T>`. So you could try changing the return type to `Task<IEnumerable<Project>>`

Comment: `yield return childProject.ChildProjects = await LoadDescendantsOf(childProject);` is kinda strange.

Answer (score 1):

You can write simple extension for this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(this T e, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenProvider)
    {
        return TraverseMany(new[] { e }, childrenProvider);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> TraverseMany<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenProvider)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<T>();
        foreach(var c in collection)
        {
            stack.Push(c);
        }
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var i = stack.Pop();
            yield return i;
            var children = childrenProvider(i);
            if (children != null)
            {
                foreach (var c in children)
                {
                    stack.Push(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And usage:

```
var allProjectIds = p.Traverse(x => x.ChildProjects).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

If you want to load subprojects I would recommend write recursive SQL procedure on cursors for this, but this will also do nice on small data:

```
var allProjectIds = p
    .Traverse(x => 
    {
       x.ChildProjects = db.Projects
                           .Where(p => p.ParentId == project.Id)
                           .ToList();
       return x.ChildProjects;
    })
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Is there an error in your `TraverseMany`-method? I get compile time error on `e` - "does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I did not compiled it. Fixed compilation error.

Comment: What is `p` in your usage examples?

Comment: It is any given project.

Comment: I seem to be stuck in an infinite loop with the second usage example.

Comment: Try to debug and find solution. If you fail to find it - create well formatted question and community will try to help you. Good luck!